# Unable to perform Speech Recognition in C++/CLI because of converting issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, speech-recognition

I am working on the following C++/cli code:

```
 #pragma once

namespace SpeechTest {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Speech::Synthesis;
    using namespace System::Speech::Recognition;
    using namespace System::Speech::AudioFormat;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(31, 28);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"speech";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 28);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button2->Text = L"text";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(31, 92);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(230, 120);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 28);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button3->Text = L"button3";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 SpeechSynthesizer synth;
                 synth.Rate = -2;
                 synth.Volume = 100;
                 synth.Speak("what is happening right now?");
             }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
             {
                 SpeechRecognizer sr;

                 array<String>^ words = gcnew array<String>(3);
                 words[0] = "red";
                 words[1] = "green";
                 words[2] = "red";

                 Choices colors;
                 colors.Add(words);

                 GrammarBuilder gb;
                 gb.Append(colors);

                 Grammar g(gb);

                 sr.LoadGrammar(g);

                 System::IntPtr ptr = gcnew System::IntPtr(&sr_SpeechRecognized);
                 sr.SpeechRecognized += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,ptr);
             }

             void sr_SpeechRecognized(System::Object ^sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
             {
             }
};
}
```

I posted this whole code so readers can know the line numbers in order to help. When I run this C++/CLI code, I get lot of errors, which I cannot solve:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SpeechTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  SpeechTest.cpp
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(132): error C3149: 'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(132): error C3149: 'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(141): error C2664: 'void System::Speech::Recognition::GrammarBuilder::Append(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Speech::Recognition::Choices' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(143): error C2664: 'System::Speech::Recognition::Grammar::Grammar(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Speech::Recognition::GrammarBuilder' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(145): error C2664: 'System::Speech::Recognition::SpeechRecognizer::LoadGrammar' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Speech::Recognition::Grammar' to 'System::Speech::Recognition::Grammar ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(147): error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\speechtest\speechtest\Form1.h(147): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

All these errors are referring to the following code snippet, which is extracted from the above

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
 {
    SpeechRecognizer sr;

    array<String>^ words = gcnew array<String>(3);
    words[0] = "red";
    words[1] = "green";
    words[2] = "red";

    Choices colors;
    colors.Add(words);

    GrammarBuilder gb;
    gb.Append(colors);

    Grammar g(gb);

    sr.LoadGrammar(g);

    System::IntPtr ptr = gcnew System::IntPtr(&sr_SpeechRecognized);
    sr.SpeechRecognized += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,ptr);
}

void sr_SpeechRecognized(System::Object ^sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
    {
    }
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: These are just the same errors you asked about in your previous question.  And already fixed by properly using the hat^ on reference type variables.  Very unclear why you decided to remove them again.  You added one more bug by completely hacking the event subscription to death.  You cannot get ahead until you learn the basics of the language syntax, covered well in any introductory book about C++/CLI programming.  Avoid asking questions about basic syntax errors, that's not what SO is about.  Visit your local library instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: No, just see, no one is able to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a `SpeechRecognizer^` at the start of your function. Don't forget to `gcnew` it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without knowing types like `Choices`. However, the `words` array should be used like this:

```
array<String^>^ words = gcnew array<String^>(3);
words[0] = "red";
words[1] = "green";
words[2] = "red";
```

Furthermore, GrammarBuilder.Append seems to expect a `String^`, but you call it with `Choices`. Similar, you need to fix the usage of `Grammar` constructor (needs `String^` instead of `GrammarBuilder`) a.s.o.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need do Add reference to your project `System::Speech` and than use next namespaces:

```
using namespace System::Speech::Synthesis;
using namespace System::Speech::Recognition;
using namespace System::Speech::AudioFormat; 

//you put a C# code instead of C++/Cli, try this:

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    SpeechSynthesizer^ synth=gcnew SpeechSynthesizer();
    synth->Rate = -2;
    synth->Volume = 100;
    synth->Speak("She say: This is real C++/Cli");

}
```

This is solution for the first button, now try your self to resolve next syntaxes. Good luck! :)